# Firebase database user info

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I’m trying to make a website where a user can login with a username a password **and a name**

This function is not implemented in firebase authentication option so I tried using its real-time database
Here is my code so far:

```
export function signup(email, password, name) {
  return auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
      db.ref("users").ref(userCredential.uid).push({
      name: name
    });
  })
}
```

Saving the data does not work but I think I have a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing only one `ref()` call and `set()` instead of `push()`:

```js
export function signup(email, password, name) {
  return auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
    db.ref("users/" + userCredential.user.uid).set({
      name: name
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks very much! I just had to change userCredential.uid to userCredential.user.uid

Comment: I've updated the answer too.